# Can you use the microphone in an Office Add In

Tags: office-js

It's possible to use the microphone from a simple web page, for example using the [Recorder.js](https://addpipe.com/simple-recorderjs-demo/) library. Since an Office Add In (e.g. a Word task pane) is basically a web page running in a browser (embedded by the Office client), I'm wondering if it's possible to use the microphone in an Add In. My initial test seem to fail, it seems the browser dialog which will ask the user for microphone access, doesn't seem to get through. Anybody can confirm or deny it's possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the browser that the add-in is using Internet Explorer, then the add-in cannot support the microphone. It should work when the add-in is using Edge. For information about which browser is used, see [Browsers used by Office Web Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins).

Comment: Thanks Rick! Do you need to give specific permissions? Or does the Add In will have the permissions to access the microphone automatically? (e.g. in a normal browser you get a dialog where you will have to confirm using the Microphone is allowed by the site)